# How do derive the cardinality of $Y=\{(x_1,x_2)\in X^2:x_1=x_2\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose we have a finite set $X$ with $|X|=n$ elements. To determine how many elements the set $X^2$ has, we use the properties of cardinality, and thus we do the following $$|X^2|=|X\times X|=|X||X|=n^2.$$ But, I struggle to derive how many elements the set $Y=\{(x_1,x_2)\in X^2:x_1=x_2\}$.

My thinking was that the set $Y$ has $\frac{1}{2}n^2$ elements since $x_1=x_2$. But this is wrong. The correct answer is $n$. Although I don't know how to justify it.

So is there a general method for calculating the number of elements of a set?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you _list_ the elements of $Y$? What elements are there?

Comment: Something like this $Y=\{(0,0),(1,0),(0,1),(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)\ldots\}$?

Comment: @johnny09 But you only want elements where both coordinates are the same. If $|X|=n$, you know $X$ has $n$ distinct elements, which you could name $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Then, for example, $(a_1,a_1) \in Y$ since $a_1=a_1$, but $(a_1,a_2)\notin Y$ since $a_1 \neq a_2$. Can you list all the ordered pairs that are in $Y$?

Comment: @kccu Okay, so $Y=\{(a_1,a_1),(a_2,a_2),(a_3,a_3),\ldots\}$, right?

Comment: @johnny09 Yes, although I would not end with $\dots$ as that makes it look like $Y$ is infinite. I would instead write $Y=\{(a_1,a_1),(a_2,a_2),\dots,(a_n,a_n)\}$.

Comment: @kccu Yes, of course, you're right. And thus $|Y|=n$. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $f: Y\to X$ be defined by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1$ then $f$ is a bijection and $|Y|=n$:

For any $x \in X$ we have $(x,x) \in Y$ so $x \in f(Y)$. If $f(x_1,x_2) = f(y_1,y_2)$ then $x_2 = x_1 = y_1 = y_2$ since both $(x_1,x_2)$ and $(y_1,y_2)$ are in $Y$. Thus $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Do you use the pigeonhole principle?

Comment: @johnny09 No, see my edit.